# Is the following code well defined according to the C99 standard?

Tags: pointers, standards, c99

A few years back, CERT issued an advisory about certain compilers optimizing away pointer overflow checks that were technically undefined in the C standard such as:

```
/* note: not the code being asked about */
#include <stdint.h>
void fn(uint32_t len) {
  char buffer[BUFLEN];
  if (buffer + len > buffer) { /* not defined if len > BUFLEN! */
    die();
  }
  /* do whatever */
}
```

After consulting the C99 standard I am now wondering if even the following code is well-defined:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main() {
  uint32_t *buf = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t) * 20);
  *(buf+10) = 100;
  return *(buf+10);
}
```

The relevant sections of the C99 standard would seem to be `6.5.6/7`, `6.5.6/8`, and `7.20.3.3/2`. My reading of the standard indicates the following:

1. `7.20.3.3/2` gives no indication that the memory allocated by `malloc` is to be considered to an array (cf `7.20.3.1` for `calloc`).
2. According to `6.5.6/7`, in an additive expression, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one.
3. `6.5.6/8` leaves undefined the result of an additive expression that would point to an element more than one past the last element of the array object. Since `6.5.6/7` indicates that in this additive expression `buf` should behave the same as a pointer to an array of length one, this would leave `buf+10` undefined.

Does this mean the second code listing above is undefined according to the C99 standard?

Comment: There's no way that the standard would deliberately outlaw the second example — one of the intended uses of `malloc()` is to allocate arrays.

Answer (score 1):

From 7.20.3:

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object *or an array of such objects* in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated.)

(Emphasis mine.)  So I think you're okay on the "malloc will give you an array" part, and once you have that the rest follows.